# Can you help identify this flowering plant (purple flowers with yellow centre)?

Tags: identification, wildflowers

I spotted this plant near the edges of a lawn near Toronto.

It produces small pink flowers about 2cm in diameter which are yellow near the centre, it has spear shaped leaves about 3cm in length.

It forms intertwined mats in the lawn, nearly like a vine would do except on the ground. Can you identify it?

See photos below:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is Convolvulus arvensis, commonly called field bindweed. They are notorious for being invasive and hard to control. It is a wild variety of the cultivated morning glory. It comes in white and pink varieties. The flowers usually open in the morning and are expended by the afternoon. The vines will grow on anything and choke out other plants.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolvulus_arvensis

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Mexican Petunia,

image from southwestnursery

[image]

image from flowerpicturegallery

[image]

I have no affiliation with them.

It is supposedly very invasive.  It looks like the only methods of control are

- pulling them out, but it can leave roots which will resprout
- herbicide

If you are planning on planting it -

> To slow down and restrict the spread of the plant, bury wood planks approximately six inches thick around it.
>
> A larger Mexican petunia should be planted in a pot and placed in an established garden. Before the plant needs to be repotted, the roots will expand within the pot and let it to blossom wonderfully for years.

From [How To Control Mexican Petunia](https://www.smileysprouts.com/flowers/how-to-control-mexican-petunia)

Comment: Leaves are not a close match, are you sure?

Comment: Flowers don't match either.